# Download gnome version of gnome tweaks rather than xfce version

Tags: repository, gnome-tweaks

I'm runnng Kubuntu 18.04. I tried to install gnome-tweaks after adding **universe** to my repositories, but I got the XFCE version rather than the gnome version.  It sort of works, but among the problems I encountered was that there was no way to quit it.  How can I replace the XFCE version by the Gnome version?

Comment: This question confuses me. XFCE uses *Window Manager* to customise the appearance of the UI, which should be incompatible with the KDE desktop that Kubuntu uses. Gnome Tweaks should also be incompatible as KDE is not Gnome. Have you replaced the KDE desktop environment on Kubuntu with something else? 

Comment: KDE has very little software in common with GNOME.  KDE's customization settings are extremely robust compared with GNOME.  What is it that you need from gnome tweaks?  Are you sure there is not already a setting in KDE for whatever 'tweak' you need to make?